# Linq select strings from list when condition is met and save the index

Tags: c#, list, linq, indexing

I have a list of strings

`List<string> lstOne = new List<string>() { "January:1", "February", "March:4"};`

And I am filtering the strings that contain : with this code

`var withcolumns = lstOne.Find(t => t.Contains(':'));`

and I am getting a new list with `{ "January:1", "March:4"}`

I want to select in a new list the values `January:1` and `March:4` but also save the indexes of then in the previous list so the result would be

> "0" "January:1" 
>   "2" "March:4"

I can be simple or complicated but right now my brain is not functioning to solve this issue.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
list.Select((item, index) => new { item, index })
    .Where(o => o.item.Contains(':'))
```

Answer (score 2):

not sure what you want as the result ?  a list of strings? or ?

but anyways.....with the index prefixed to your string...

```
List<string> lstOne = new List<string>() { "January:1", "February", "March:4" };
var list = lstOne.Select((s, i) => i+ " " + s ).Where(s => s.Contains(":")).ToList();
```